# Lambda Authorizer does not work if changes URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a serverless API, with Node(TS) Lambda e ApiGateway. I created a custom LambdaAuthorizer. At first, it works, for example:

- first I call my endpoint to create a token (returns a JWT): POST **/Stage/token**
- then I call the endpoint POST **entries/f5415748-0f85-49c0-a94e-eb9a5f200d/commit** and pass the JWT above it in the "Authorization" header. It works.
- then if I call POST **/entries/{otherId}/commit** using the same token, it returns 403

I think this is related to the code that generates the policy

```
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource, decoded) {
  var authResponse = {};
  
  authResponse.principalId = principalId;
  if (effect && resource) {
      var policyDocument = {};
      policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
      policyDocument.Statement = [];
      var statementOne = {};
      statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
      statementOne.Effect = effect;
      statementOne.Resource = resource;
      policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
      authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
  }
  
  authResponse.context = {
      "userId": decoded.userId
  };

  return authResponse;
}
```

So how can I use the same token for different ids?

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
 statementOne.Resource = resource;
```

for

```
 statementOne.Resource = '*';
```

It worked, although I'm not sure this is the best and more secure way.